# Erro ao renomear arquivo txt em JAVA

Tags: java

Olá!
Preciso renomear um arquivo `txt`, esse `txt` é esquema para log do sistema. Cada dia possui seu `log.txt`. Estou usando os seguintes parâmetros para validar o arquivo e renomear, se o arquivo existe e se a primeira linha do arquivo é a data atual, caso não seja, o arquivo deve ser renomeado (Foi a única forma que encontrei, também aceito sugestões para fazer melhor).

> Código

```
   //connTXT.getPath() = "C:\\Users\\" + nomePc + "\\Documents\\Logs\\log.txt";
   File file = new File(connTXT.getPath());


   if(file.exists() && !linha.equals(dataAtual)){

   //connTXT.getDiretorioPastaLog() = "C:\\Users\\" + nomePc + "\\Documents\\Logs";

    // Renomear o arquivo
   file.renameTo(new File(connTXT.getDiretorioPastaLog(),"Teste.txt")); // <== Dúvidas aqui

    }
```

Não apresenta erros visíveis, apenas não renomeia o arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma pasta temporária 'tmpLog' e colocar o `log.txt` nela temporariamente e depois de fazer a verificação da data e da primeira linha, pode usar o `File.move();` para uma pasta definitiva.

Comment: Vou verificar, apesar de estar corrido aqui esses dias e não voltei a mexer no projeto. Assim que eu conseguir no fim de semana compartilho com vocês. Irei experimentar a técnica de criar uma pasta temporário ou até mesmo usar a pasta `temp` do Windows. Também irei depurar para verificar se o arquivo se encontra aberto no momento de renomear. Desde já agradeço a todos.